In ASP.NET on .NET 4.8, does the StreamContent get buffered by ASP.NET or IIS?
I'm used to working with .NET 6+ self hosted Web API, but now I'm working on an ASP.NET Web API running on .NET 4.8 and hosted in IIS.
I'm creating an endpoint to download files and they can be very large (up to 1 GB).
Here is a simplified example:
public HttpResponseMessage Download(string filename)
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var fileStream = GetFileStream(filename);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);

    return response;
}

I've been trying to verify that the stream does not get buffered into memory, either by ASP.NET or IIS, before delivering it to the caller, but I can't find any documentation that explains it one way or the other.
Based on my testing I think it's not getting buffered, but I would like to be 100% sure.
Can anyone tell me for sure if StreamContent does or does not get fully buffered into memory?
Edit: updated to better reflect what I'm dealing with. Assume that GetFileStream() method is a service that returns a stream to the source file.

Depends on your exact pipeline, there are some middlewares that need to do extra parsing so will need to buffer.

In your example, it probably suggests that the whole file is read into memory.
However, you can use the built in transmit file, and it most certainly does not pull the whole file into memory.
Hence, say this to download a file:
        string strFileOnly = "catalog.pdf"

        strFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/UpLoadFiles/" + strFileOnly);

        string sMineType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strFileOnly);
        Response.ContentType = sMineType;
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileOnly);
        Response.TransmitFile(strFile);
        Response.End();

So, the "key" in above is using Response.TransmitFile(). Thus the sending of the file is not buffered and loaded into memory first. This choice thus reduces required server memory, and the file is not loaded into memory first. Hence, the file is read in small parts and sent to the client for you.
As to if IIS or your code behind is sending the file?
In any case in which you have code behind, then of course since you are using code to read the file, then your server code and not IIS is sending that file. I suppose one could state that both IIS and your code behind are working together for such downloads.
If you provide a valid URL link, then of course no code behind is required, and thus of course the web server (IIS) is sending the file and not your code behind, since you not written any code.
In near all cases, using TransmitFile() is a better choice then using code and some kind of stream choice, which in most cases will be loading the whole file into memory.
TransmistFile() is thus the most efficient "practical" choice when writing code to send a file to the browser.

HttpResponseMessage does not have a TransmistFile() method. Where is that method defined?

Why do you say "some kind of stream choice, which in most cases will be loading the whole file into memory". Stream do not typically load the source into memory. Streams are designed to allow streaming of bytes from source to destination without reading the entire source into memory. That is the while point of streams. So what is causing the stream source to be read into memory?

Well, it depends on how you feed the stream object, right? If you feed it a ReadAllbytes, then you feeding the stream the whole file. So, sure, not always the case that a file stream will load all of the file - but often it will depending on the code used. As for HttpResponseMessge? You look to be correct, it not available in a web api project (and I did not know that). for my api projects, I tend to create a standard web project, and then add web methods and end points. So, right now, I did not realize that the HttpResponse does not seem to support nor have Transmitfile as a opiton.

So, my apologies, I did not realize that web api projects don't support transmit file. Given that being the case, then a file stream could be used, but using "async" methods should allow one to obtain reduced memory use.  Quite sure you need to set or control buffer size (along with seek I think). As I stated, that's why I used the word "practical" in terms of using Transmist file - so there are other approaches, but they take extra work on your part. So, a filestream with async methods should reduce memory requirements, but with Transmit file, I not had to go down those other possibilities.
